# How read content of local entry from registry resource

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using local entry to register the parameters and not to leave fixed in the artifacts, I do not know if it is better solution.

Everything works when I create the local entry in ESB Config, but when I create in the project registry resource I can not read correctly.

I am using code below to read local entry and write to a property:

```
<Property description = "SetPPSUserName" expression = "get-property ('registry', 'conf: /local-entries/PPS_Username.xml')" name = "SetPPSUserName" scope = "default" type = "STRING" />
```

Problem, is that it loads the entire xml contents of the local entry and not only the content, example as the property:

```
SetPPSUserName = "<localEntry key="PPS_Username" xmlns="​http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><![CDATA [content test blablab]]></ localEntry>"
```

Correct would be:

```
SetPPSUserName = "content test blablab"
```

NOTE: When I upload the CAR to the site, the local entry of the project registry resource does not appear in the local entry list of the management console.

Message translated from Portuguese to English with google translator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Set type = OM in property instead of STRING.

```
<Property description = "SetPPSUserName" expression = "get-property ('registry', 'conf: /local-entries/PPS_Username.xml')" name = "SetPPSUserName" scope = "default" type = "OM" />

<log level="custom">
<property name="call_testProp" expression="$ctx:SetPPSUserName" type="STRING"/>
</log>
```

UPDATE 1:

My localEntry inside registry:

```
<localEntry key="PPS_Usernamelocal" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<a>
  <b>TEST</b>
</a>
</localEntry>
```

My property and log mediator inside an esb proxy:

```
 <property name="PPS_Username"
           expression="get-property('registry','conf:/localentries/PPS_Username.xml')"
           scope="default"
           type="OM"/>        
 <log level="custom">
    <property name="PPS_UsernameB" expression="$ctx:PPS_Username//syn:a/syn:b" xmlns:syn="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>                                        
 </log>
```

My ESB response:

```
[2017-02-22 16:21:42,680]  INFO - LogMediator PPS_UsernameB = TEST
```

Comment: It does not work, it is returning entire XML instead of just the content.

I think I'll have to use XPATH to load only the content.

Comment: sure, just $ctx:SetPPSUserName//prex:element for example, in your question you put bla bla bla, so it´s not a valid xml :-D but my answer it´s ok.

Comment: The problem is not blalbalba, but rather it returns the entire statement "<localEntry key =" PPS_Username "xmlns =" http: //ws.apache.org/n ....... "  instead of just the content

The ideal was to work just like the "local entry" that sits inside the ESB Config Project, just by passing the name, it returns the content.

Comment: It does not work as "Local Entry" but rather as XML, instead of declaring a "Local Entry", I can declare the content directly in the xml that will work, for me it is problem

Comment: ok, take a look to my update 1, it work with xml content inside the localEntry, just using the synapse namespace

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got it right.

If you want to access a registry resource within a proxy you have to execute the following steps.

1.) create "Registry Resource Project"
2.) add a "Registry Resource" to that project. Because I faced some problems in the past with creating resources directly in dev studio, I always create a test/XML file with the content on my local disk and select "Import from file  system"  wen creating the resource 
3.) create a CAR for the "Registry Resource Project"
4.) Open the pom.xml from the CAR project and change the "Server role" to "EnterpriseServiceBus" otherwise it won't get deployed to the ESB.
5.) Export the CAR and deploy it to the Server

Then you're able to access it inside the Proxy like this.

```
<property name="registryValue" expression="get-property('registry','gov:/path/property1.txt')"/>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But instead of a PROPERTY1.TXT I'd like to use a "Local Entry".

But instead of a PROPERTY1.TXT I'd like to use a "Local Entry".

And then get-property returns the contents of "Local Entry" and not the entire XML.